# Apply cumsum function using condition

Tags: r, if-statement, cumsum

I am trying to calculate the maximum number of aircraft on the ground simultaneously throughout the year per station, knowing that I have more than 300 stations and that the data is per (day and hours) for 1 year.

So I thought of this solution: find the maximum per day and per station then extract the maximum per station.

my data are in this format: station, aircraft ,time , type ( arrive to the station or depart from the station) and value is 1 if is arrival and -1 if is depart, I create this column to facilitate the count, the idea is apply cumsum once the data are sorted by time for each station.

[image]

I need to create a function which group the data by day and by station and count the cumulative sum,  but I have planes that have been sleeping in the station, so I need to delete them( the yellows lines in the screenshot).
The trick to detect these planes:
Aircraft allows us to track the plane:
generally it appears twice a day when it arrives and when it leaves.
to detect these planes that I have to look
the variables: **Aircraft and Type**:
if the type is **departure** and the aircraft variable of this **line appears only once in this day**, ( it means there is no arrival for this flight)  **then I should not count them.**

I was thinking to create a function: to group by (station and time) then apply cumsum but skipping the lines with the conditions that I explained before.(if the type is **departure** and the aircraft variable of this **line appears only once in this day**, then I should not count them)

Any Help??

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating new table `Tab1` with Table function to count the frequency of the aircrafts by day,  then I joined this table to my original data base to then delete the ones with `freq=1` and `type=departure`.

```
tab<- as.data.frame(table(df$day,df$AIRCRAFT, useNA = "always"))
df_new<-df%>% left_join(tab,by=c("day"="Var1","AIRCRAFT" = "Var2"))

df_final<-df_new%>% group_by(day)%>% filter(TYPE=="Departure",Freq==1)%>% arrange(TIMESTAMP)%>% group_by(day) %>% 
  mutate(ground= cumsum(Freq))
```